# I keep getting this compiling error: ceasar.c:9:1: error: expected identifier or '(' {

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50

Hey all I have been trying to do the Cs50 course with harvard and am doing the 2nd week Ceasar assignment. For some reason I can't seem to solve this error and I can't seem to locate what the problem is. I've tried changing the bracket style from { to [ and ( but that isn't working and as far as I can tell I've declared everything correctly. It may have something to do with the semi at the end of the int main() but when I remove it I get another error telling me it should be there. The error message is ceasar.c:9:1: error: expected identifier or '(' {    referring to the { between the int num = and the k == argv. I've posted the code below. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>


int main(int argc, string argv[]);
int num;

{
k == argv[2];
        
        if(argc != 2)
        {
                printf("K not included in command");
                return 1;
        }
                


        string s = get_string("Insert Lowercase Message:");

        for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s); i < n; i++)
        {
                if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
                {
                        num = s[i] - 'A';
                        
                }
                else if (s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z')
                {
                        num = s[i] - 'a';
                }
                Output[i] = (num + k)%26;
        }

        printf("Secret message %s\n", output[i]);

}
```

Comment: (1) Get rid of the semicolon after `int main(int argc, string argv[]);`.

Comment: (2) move `int num;` after first opening `{`.

Comment: (3) `k == argv[2];` is meaningless.  I think you want `k = atoi(argv[1]);`.  Also move it after the "K not included in command" test.

Comment: Get a couple of decent books about C to read, and take classes. That will teach you C much better than CS50 can (and don't use so-called "competition" or "online judge" sites, that's not what they're for).

Comment: (5) Declare `k`

Comment: (4) `printf("Secret message %s\n", output[i]);` is wrong.  It should be `printf("Secret message %s\n", output);`.  (Although there are other problems with `output`.)

Comment: Some programmer dude is right.  You could do worse than https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/cclass.html

Comment: `int main(int argc, string argv[])` is non-standard. What is `string`? Is it `typedef` for `char*`?

Comment: (6) at some point after doing `(num + k)%26`, you have to add in `'a'` or `'A'`. (7) At some point, you have to null-terminate `output`.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `string` is a CS50 convenience shorthand (yes, a typedef)  for `char *`.  Evidently it's intended to make things less confusing for beginners who haven't learned about pointers yet.  Needless to say it makes things much more confusing.

Comment: @SteveSummit I see. Well - how convenient. A non-standard `typedef` that very few have heard about, to replace `char*` that ... everybody knows. :-)

Comment: The CS50 library tries really hard to abstract away the grosser parts of string handling and I/O in C, but in the process sets students up for failure later on.   You basically have to unlearn everything and start over.

Comment: The poor spacing/indentation makes the code unclear:(

Answer (score 1):

The following lines are problematic:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]);
int num;

{
k == argv[2];
        
        if(argc != 2)
```

1. You need to remove the semicolon after `main`;
2. You need to mov `int num` to *after* the opening `{`;
3. You need a declaration for `k`;
4. You need to check the number of arguments *before* attempting to assign `argv[2]` to `k`;
5. If you are expecting 2 arguments (`argc == 2`), then the second argument is at `argv[1]`, not `argv[2]`;
6. You need to use `=` for assignment, not `==`;
7. `k` is an `int`, whereas `argv[1]` points to a *string representation* of an integer value; you will need to use `atoi` or `strtol` to convert the contents of `argv[1]` to the equivalent integer value;

Putting that all together:

```
#include <stdlib.h> // for atoi
...
int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  int num;
  int k;

  if ( argc != 2 )
    // error

  k = atoi( argv[1] );
```

and proceed from there.

Some words of warning - the CS50 library ***grossly*** misrepresents how strings and string processing work in C.  Do not expect anything you learn in this course with respect to strings to carry forward in other environments.